# How can we check out automatically after approving the Document?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

Iam using the sharepoint default approval workflow on some libraries,here my question is after approving the particular document
the document in the library has to be checked out automatically,so that the user will not change anything in the approved document
(i.e after approved no one should not permission to change the document content).

can anyone please give some sort of solution for my issue.

Thanks in Advance,
Naresh.

Answer (score 1):

I don't entirely agree that checking out after approval is the right way to go. I would instead update permissions so that users can only read the document. That being said, you understand your requirements more than I do so maybe check out is what you really need. I don't know.

Regardless of which way you go, [permissions](http://sridharu.blogspot.com/2008/12/sharepoint-assigning-permission.html) or [check out](http://www.novolocus.com/2009/02/05/wss-practice-checking-inout-documents-and-versioning/), you will probably end up performing the action within [event receivers](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brianwilson/archive/2007/03/05/part-1-event-handlers-everything-you-need-to-know-about-microsoft-office-sharepoint-portal-server-moss-event-handlers.aspx). Specifically I would use the ItemUpdated event receiver. This allows you to perform actions based on changes that were made to the document - e.g. check approval status and act accordingly.

I would use Updated instead of Updating because I imagine if you check out a document before its officially been updated you may run into some goofy things. But you can try both!